# Use GCM without publishing app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app which I want to use within my friend circle I don't want to publish app on google play. Can I use the GCM service by keeping my application in draft mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that, I have integrated GCM in my app.

You just need to create and host your own server that will behave as third party sever for registering device and sending messages to GCM Server.

You can get the Sender Key and API Key from Google Console that has to be used at Client and Server respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that..

```
static void register(final Context context, String name, String email, final String regId) {
//indented code
    Log.i(TAG, "registering device (regId = " + regId + ")");
    String serverUrl = SERVER_URL;
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("regId", regId);
    params.put("name", name);
    params.put("email", email);

    long backoff = BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS + random.nextInt(1000);
    // Once GCM returns a registration id, we need to register on our server
    // As the server might be down, we will retry it a couple
    // times.
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempt #" + i + " to register");
        try {
            displayMessage(context, context.getString(
                    R.string.server_registering, i, MAX_ATTEMPTS));
            post(serverUrl, params);
            GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
            String message = context.getString(R.string.server_registered);
            CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Here we are simplifying and retrying on any error; in a real
            // application, it should retry only on unrecoverable errors
            // (like HTTP error code 503).
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to register on attempt " + i + ":" + e);
            if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                break;
            }
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Sleeping for " + backoff + " ms before retry");
                Thread.sleep(backoff);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // Activity finished before we complete - exit.
                Log.d(TAG, "Thread interrupted: abort remaining retries!");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            }
            // increase backoff exponentially
            backoff *= 2;
        }
    }
    String message = context.getString(R.string.server_register_error,
            MAX_ATTEMPTS);
    CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
}

/**
 * Unregister this account/device pair within the server.
 */
static void unregister(final Context context, final String regId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "unregistering device (regId = " + regId + ")");
    String serverUrl = SERVER_URL + "/unregister";
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("regId", regId);
    try {
        post(serverUrl, params);
        GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, false);
        String message = context.getString(R.string.server_unregistered);
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // At this point the device is unregistered from GCM, but still
        // registered in the server.
        // We could try to unregister again, but it is not necessary:
        // if the server tries to send a message to the device, it will get
        // a "NotRegistered" error message and should unregister the device.
        String message = context.getString(R.string.server_unregister_error,
                e.getMessage());
        CommonUtilities.displayMessage(context, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it without publishing the app. As Nargis said, you need to create your own server.

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) you have a great tutorial, hope it helps.

Comment: The tutorial linked above creates an app. How can you register and store a registration id without an app? Is that possible from android chrome browser?